# Matplotlib : how to chose a color for each specific value in an array for mathshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I searched and found I can create a colormap, but I feel that kinda too much for what I want to do.
Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
A=[1,1,1,1,1]
B=[0,0,0,0,0]
C=[0,0,3,0,0]
D=[0,0,0,0,0]
E=[2,2,2,2,2]
plateau=np.array([E,D,C,B,A])

def aff_graph():
    ax=np.arange(-0.5,5,1)
    plt.matshow(plateau)
    for z in ax:
        plt.plot((z,z),(ax[0],ax[5]),'k-')
        plt.plot((ax[0],ax[5]),(z,z),'k-')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
```

It gives me this : [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4rMX.png)

But actually I'd like to set it like this :

0→white

1→green

2→red

3→black

I only need this, and not a color map for values in a certain interval. How could I do the easiest way ?

Bonus question : is there any way to make all the squares white, with a colored circle inside ? Since it's a board for a game, I think it would better convey.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go for the bonus question only:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches


A=[1,1,1,1,1]
B=[0,0,0,0,0]
C=[0,0,3,0,0]
D=[0,0,0,0,0]
E=[2,2,2,2,2]
plateau=np.array([E,D,C,B,A])

plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
plt.gca().set(aspect='equal')

for i in range(6):
    plt.plot([i,i],[0,5],'k')
    plt.plot([0,5],[i,i],'k')

for i1 in range(5):
    for i2 in range(5):
        color_idx = plateau[i1, i2]
        if color_idx == 1:
            plt.gca().add_patch(mpatches.Circle((i2+0.5,i1+0.5), 0.3, fc='green'))
        if color_idx == 2:
            plt.gca().add_patch(mpatches.Circle((i2+0.5,i1+0.5), 0.3, fc='red'))
        if color_idx == 3:
            plt.gca().add_patch(mpatches.Circle((i2+0.5,i1+0.5), 0.3, fc='black'))    

plt.show()
```

which gives

[image: this]

### Edit:

In order to be able to update the figure, you can put the plotting of the circles into a function. Each time you call the function, it should first delete all old circles before drawing the new, like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from time import sleep

# initialize figure and grid
fig = plt.figure()
plt.axis('off')
plt.gca().set(aspect='equal')
for i in range(6):
    plt.plot([i,i], [0,5], 'k')
    plt.plot([0,5], [i,i], 'k')


def draw_circles(plateau):
    # remove all circles
    for child in plt.gca().get_children():
        if type(child).__name__ == 'Circle':
            child.remove()

    # draw new circles
    for i1 in range(5):
        for i2 in range(5):
            color_idx = plateau[i1, i2]
            if color_idx == 1:
                circle = mpatches.Circle((i2+0.5, i1+0.5), 0.3, fc='green')
            if color_idx == 2:
                circle = mpatches.Circle((i2+0.5, i1+0.5), 0.3, fc='red')
            if color_idx == 3:
                circle = mpatches.Circle((i2+0.5, i1+0.5), 0.3, fc='black')
            plt.gca().add_patch(circle)

    plt.show(block=False)


# draw for first time
A = [1,1,1,1,1]
B = [0,0,0,0,0]
C = [0,0,3,0,0]
D = [0,0,0,0,0]
E = [2,2,2,2,2]
draw_circles(plateau=np.array([E, D, C, B, A]))

# update after some time
sleep(2)
A = [1,1,1,1,1]
B = [0,0,3,0,0]
C = [0,0,0,0,0]
D = [0,0,0,0,0]
E = [2,2,2,2,2]
draw_circles(plateau=np.array([E, D, C, B, A]))

plt.show()
```

You can call this function every n seconds, or have it triggered by some kind of event, like a callback of some button click or so. However I need to add that I don't really understand the behavior of the `plt.show(block=False)` command, and in fact I was not able to redraw the figure more than two times before the figure freezes ... if you have trouble with that, too, it might be worth asking a separate question.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. That is perfect, thank you. However is there anyway to rotate the graph, so the reds are upside and greens downside ? Without changing color attribution of course.

Comment: Also, how can I make it update automatically as values of A,B,C,D,E (and thus plateau's too) vary ? I put the function in a loop but it stacks new windows of graph each time I want to display it, so I guess it would be better to put the function only once, and set it so it updates itself every x seconds.

Comment: @Daniel I have added a second version of the code that allows the figure to be updated.

Answer (score 3):

That can be achieved with the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

A=[1,1,1,1,1]
B=[0,0,0,0,0]
C=[0,0,3,0,0]
D=[0,0,0,0,0]
E=[2,2,2,2,2]

plateau=np.array([E,D,C,B,A])

c = mpl.colors.ListedColormap(['white', 'green', 'red', 'black'])
n = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0,vmax=3)

def aff_graph():
    ax=np.arange(-0.5,5,1)
    plt.matshow(plateau,cmap=c,norm=n)
    for z in ax:
        plt.plot((z,z),(ax[0],ax[5]),'k-')
        plt.plot((ax[0],ax[5]),(z,z),'k-')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
aff_graph()
```

I added 2 lines of code: the first one creates the desired colormap, using the colors you asked. With that, your example already works fine.

However, let's say that a given **plateau** does not contain the number 3, but only 0s, 1s and 2s. That would lead to the following undesired color assignment:

> 0→white 
> 1→red 
> 2→black

The second line that I added takes care of that. It defines the normalization to be used, making sure that the color scheme is solid. You might not even need that if all four colors are always there (don't know how the game works).

Of course, make sure that you set the *cmap* and *norm* options when calling *matshow*. Now, even if not all colors are present, you still get the result you want:
[image]